# Does Direct Memory affect compressed Pointers in Java?

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I am aware that once Java heap size grows past 32GB, we lose the benefits of compressed pointers and may have less effective memory (compared to 32GB) until the total heap reaches ~48GB.

Does Direct Memory usage affect the determination to use compressed pointers or not? For example, will I still be able to use them with settings like `-Xmx28G -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=12G`?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I must respectfully but strongly disagree.

Comment: Yeah, it's the user's choice, and there's usually more factors than just memory usage to consider. I understand that Some Things Are Big, regardless of language, but the larger a program grows, the more you notice the benefit of switching to C++. I just put it out as a suggestion.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Thats... very... opinionated. While there are arguably scenarios where you opinion will be spot on, there are also arguably those where its not. Without knowing anything about the use case the statement is just speculation and better kept in ones private thought, not put as a comment.

Comment: I agree, it's more of an opinion than fact, I just can't think of cases where a large Java program would have a smaller memory footprint than the same program in C++. I will refrain from more comments like these in future.

Comment: I don't know, but I bet direct memory is not part of java space and it should not affect things related to object references.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson a 64-bit C++ program uses 64-bit pointers and if you use shared_ptr this can use 48 bytes. It all depends on how you program it as to whether it uses more memory or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am aware that once Java heap size grows past 32GB, we lose the benefits of compressed pointers and may have less effective memory (compared to 32GB) until the total heap reaches ~48GB.

You can increase the object alignment to 16 (in Java) allowing you to use CompressedOops up to 64 GB.

> Does Direct Memory usage affect the determination to use compressed pointers or not?

The direct memory is just native memory like the thread stacks, GUI components, shared libraries etc.  They are not part of the heap, nor is the meta space.

> For example, will I still be able to use them with settings like -Xmx28G -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=12G

You can have `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024G` if you like, this is not part of the heap.